# Considerations for hypothetical ship designs using a gravity generator for propulsion?

Tags: space-travel, spaceships

Edit: I'm exploring an idea for a hypothetically possible form of propulsion for a sci-fi story. My question is if, based on what I describe below, other folks might have some ideas about how the construction and operation of such vehicles might work.

As some general scope to the question, this isn't describing any kind of warp drive or FTL. Rather, it proposes a what-if scenario where a gravity field/source can be produced artificially on demand in front of a spacecraft.

First, two assumptions. One, gravity has a particle (vs being a side effect of mass on space time. Lot of debate in the physics community around this but supported by the Standard Model). Two, a technology can be created to create gravitons on demand.

Ok, given that imagine a potential kind of reactionless spacecraft propulsion. A ship has a long projection in front of it. At the end of that projection is a gravity generator that produces a gravity well of some amount. Let’s say 1G for the example.

The idea is that such a ship could essentially produce a gravity well in front of it that it falls into. It doesn’t have to be a constant field. Maybe the generator alternates on/off to help move things along.

I have some ideas about the internals of such a craft could be configured. Like, each deck could be built so the floors always point to the front of the ship. To slow down, the ship rotates 180 degrees so the gravity field is now in the inverse direction of travel.

With the exception of the hypothetical gravity generator, I can imagine being able to build spacecraft like this using today's technology. Power sources might be solar, fission, RTG, etc.

What are some other considerations we'd have to make when designing craft like this?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Geuis! If you have a moment, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You'll also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6168) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods. Have fun!

Comment: I'm sorry but could you please clarify a bit more what was your question? I mean, at the bottom of your post write: "So, my question is..." Thanks

Comment: Thanks @EnderLook. Added some more details and updated the wording a bit.

Comment: I am having a bit of difficulty visualizing this, as the image always becomes one of trying to lift myself up by my bootstraps. Every action occurs equally in opposite directions. Pulling your body up is also pulling your hands down. How do you push something ahead of you which in turn pulls you towards it at the same time? Pushing something ahead also pushes you back equally. But another vision I have is surfing a gravitational wave, where the wave is produced by pushing something ahead of you.

Comment: @JustinThyme Here's how I'm thinking about it. Gravity travels at the speed of light. Most of the mass your spacecraft is behind the generator. So if you just turned it on, you're right since its all attached together. No movement. But if you time it so that when the gravity waves hit the ship and the generator is off, then you should get a marginal "pull" towards the source of the wave. If you repeat this over and over, you should get gradual acceleration.

Comment: @Geuis To point at where I think Justin is having trouble, what you are describing is basically an action without an equal and opposite reaction.  There is a force on the ship, but there is no corresponding reaction force on the device creating the gravitons.  If this was a "real" source of gravity, such as a black hole, it is easy to see that while the ship would be pulled forward, it would also crush the projection because the black hole is "hard to move."

Comment: Apart from the action without reaction problem which upsets a whole lot of physics as we know it, there is another problem. Gravitons are the postulated field particles of the gravitational field, that is they mediate the gravitational force,  which is related to distortions of spacetime. Currently, the only way we know how to distort spacetime is through mass. Now, a more accurate way of describing your drive is that it is a device that allows the user to project a dimple in spacetime without there actually being any mass present.

Comment: What you are describing sounds like a surfer throwing big rocks behind him to create a wave that he can surf, and then she throws another rock to create another wave, and so on and so on. (Except that it is the generator that is throwing the gravity rocks). The energy for forward momentum comes from the 'rock slinger', or in this case, the gravity generator. As long as you did not try to recover the energy you used to create the gravity well, it would not be 'bootstrapping'.

Comment: @GretchenV It would almost seem that this 'generator' is somehow manipulating the Higgs field. Since we do not fully understand the complete implications of the Higgs field on gravity, what exactly would a distortion of the Higgs field result in? It would, of course, take considerable amounts of energy to do so. The action-reaction thing would be that the 'bubble' would pull everything AHEAD of it, not just what was BEHIND it. The opposite would be throwing a bomb ahead of you on earth - once the bomb exploded, it pushes you back but also pushes everything back AHEAD of it.

Comment: When a bomb goes off, stationary  in front of you, it pushes you back, but by pushing you back, the origin of the explosion itself is not moved. That is, when the blast wave hits you, you slow the blast wave down (opposite reaction), and may even deflect the blast wave back, but you do not push the point of the original source of the blast away. But this is the conundrum of gravity - if it imparts kinetic energy, why is the amount of gravitational energy not diminished when converted to another form?

Comment: And, as an aside, wouldn't the gravitons be equivalent to 'reaction mass', even though they are massless?

Comment: @JustinThyme While the Higgs field (or rather the non-zero vacuum expectation value of it) endows most particles with intrinsic mass, most of the mass we experience results from the binding energy (energy==mass) of quarks in baryons. Now, this is world building and there is no tag hard science or science based, so it is much easier to postulate a workable relativistic quantum theory of gravity (we don't have one of these at the moment) that permits distortions of space time (which would generate gravitons) without mass. Suspension of disbelief is key in discussing space travel.

Comment: @GretchenV  So, essentially, close enough for science fiction. Incidentally, I can argue that it should be space/time, rather than spacetime, because the first three dimensions are multiplied to get to the next (in the numerator) as in  area=length x width,  but time is a dimension that is divided (in the denominator) to go to the next level, as in speed = m/s or acceleration = m/s/s. It makes it easier to visualize why you can not go from 3D to 4D the way you visualize from 2D to 3D. You DIVIDE the time dimension, not multiply it.

Comment: @GretchenV and shouldn't 'intrinsic mass' be 'inertial mass'?

Comment: ' Like, each deck could be built so the floors always point to the front of the ship.' We perceive the smooth motion of video from a rapid sequence of still images because of persistence of vision. Same with using 60 hertz lighting, to illuminate our rooms. Would turning a gravity generator on and off rapidly have the same effect? Would our bodies experience a 'persistence of gravity'? Would there ever be the gravitational equivalent of 'we see the wheels are turning backwards' because they are turning at slightly faster than the hertz rate of the movie camera, when something 'falls'?

Comment: @JustinThyme Yes, intrinsic mass -> inertial mass, but as for spacetime instead of space/time, read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime. In terms of general relativity what is important is the distance between two points in spacetime. Speed and acceleration are derived quantities (and speed is relative anyway - it depends on the observer)

Comment: @GretchenV We are at risk of being sen to chat, but I could give you a mathematical treatise in favor of calling it space/time.

Comment: _[Singularity Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_Sky)_ I don't need to say anything else I don't think.

Comment: I own that novel. Doesn’t have anything to do with my question.

Answer (score 2):

**Some Troubles**

A trough in space-time in front of your ship will not do anything unless there is a corresponding ridge created behind it. Its more like surfing on a wave of space-time than it is falling. Its also inertialess so its technically not motion at all so much as a change in location that is occurring constantly as you warp space around you. You are basically just proposing a psuedo-scientific handwavey way to create an Alcumbierre drive without using exotic matter, negative mass, or literally astronomical volumes of energy. This comes with a few problems however.

**The Trough Catches Stuff**

That trough in space time is going to be collecting literally everything that gets in the way and moves it along with the ship. This means every single speck of dust, radioactive particle, hydrogen atom, high energy particle etc etc. Once the ship stops this is going to be propelled on a bow-wave along whatever path you were traveling in at the speed of light. You will obliterate whatever you are trying to reach simply by reaching it. The fact that we aren't detecting such crazy bursts of radiation and catastrophic ripples in space-time means that this method of travel doesn't work, there aren't any intelligent races using it, or that our model for gravity is wrong. (Hint: Our evidence for gravity working the way it does is pretty strong.) But it's Science Fantasy so it doesn't have to be totally accurate, but you do need to mcguffin up a solution to the solar system frying tsunami of gamma rays, relativistic particles, and planet orbit shattering distortions in the local space time.

**Catastrophic Gravitational Issues**

Turns out the radioactive particle tsunami is actually a minor side effect of something a bit more scary. See, that tidal wave of highly radioactive particles moving at light speed is being borne upon a sort of splash-wave of space-time. So as you exit your "jump" you are going to be releasing such a huge space-time distortion that weird stuff starts happening. Think if you had a bunch of beach balls arranged in a pool and some guy did a cannon-ball into the water. That, except with planets. Also weird temporal distortions I'm not smart enough to explain would happen too, except nobody would be around to see it since they'd be too busy frying to death in all the horrible radiation to notice that their planet was flying off into a new orbit, and since they're stuck in the temporal distortion they wouldn't notice that time wasn't flowing properly anyways. The Horrified crew of your ship are outside observers though so they would get to watch them all die in really funky distorted time-rates, so that's kinda neat. If you don't think watching entire solar systems be destroyed every time you jump then you will need to bust that handwavium out and mgcuffin up a solution for why this doesn't happen too.

**Temporal Issues**

So even though the Alcumbierre space-time warp method of travel doesn't necessarily move the ship kinetically at faster than light speed, its still subject to a lot of relativistic laws regarding temporal phenomenon. Namely, that if you move past the speed of light time actually starts moving backwards. This means that you would actually show up somewhere before you left. This causes all sorts of crazy time paradoxes that I'm far too unintelligent to understand. But its bad stuff. Bad stuff happens when you break time. You probably need more handwavium and mcguffinite to fix this.

**Ultimately it's a Non-issue for the Story**

See, thing is, FTL is already not possible. FTl is pretty much literally spcae-magic in any science based story. The idea for your ship can work however you want it to without any of the horrific implications of the big "what if" scenario in which we pretend FTL would work with real physics. Point being, The deck-plan of your fictional ship isn't the biggest part of the story you really need to be worried about if you are going to go for hard science here. I'm only really giving you a blue-collar layman's view of why FTL occurring would be pretty horrific for all involved, but if some guy *DID* get FTL to work it would basically be a cosmic disaster every time they fired it up.

Comment: Thanks for the response @TCAT117. I'm not sure, but I suspect you started thinking about your response while I was updating the question. What I'm thinking is specifically *not* a warp drive or FTL system. Rather, its entirely relativistic. At the idea's core, rather than *pushing* the vehicle its being *pulled*. By creating an artificial gravity well ahead of the vehicle, the craft falls toward the source and gains acceleration in that manner.

Comment: That's how a warp drive works bruh. A gravity well is a warp in space time.

Comment: There are some interesting considerations about attracting debris and energetic particles that encounter the artificial field. Suppose gravitons are like neutrinos in that they don't interact with EM fields, so they will be expelled in every direction and draw things towards the generator. This could be a bad thing! Alternatively, say you can focus your gravitons just towards the ship. A lot of those problems might be avoidable.

Comment: Hah right, technically this would be a "warp drive" in the sense that mass emits gravitons (in this hypothetical situation) so all stars/planets etc are "warp drives". But with this idea, its not a Star Trek FTL drive. Its simply a gravity point source that can be turned on and off. While its on, it would bend space but not like in Alcubierre drive.

Comment: Again, I refer to my statement earlier in my answer. Substitute FTL with the word magic. We're discussing something that is fundamentally impossible so its really whatever you want it to be. I simply detailed some known physics and the effects they have.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I'm pretty sure you aren't getting the core concept I'm describing but that's ok.

Comment: No I get it, its just made up and wouldn't work unless you decide to ignore a lot of proven physics.

Comment: @Geuis Don't mind him. There are a lot of people around here who do not recognize the difference between 'proven physics' and 'speculative physics'. To some, physics is a religion, adhered to with ideological fanaticism. 'All Truth is Known, and the PhysicsTextbook is the Repository of that Truth'.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, just imagine the empire state building, and the tip of the antenna is the gravity well generator. The bottom of the ship is a giant thruster that pushes you forward with 1 g of force. Now everyone can stand around the office and talk and drink from the water coolers and stuff. Some floors would be apartments, others recreation or resteraunts or whatever you want. Just make sure in between each floor is a giant flipper that can revolve the floor so it's facing the opposite direction for when you start decelerating. Again, at 1 g so that you have basically normal gravity. And then whenever you decide to stop everyone needs to strap in and seal everything up so it doesn't float everywhere.

Also, everything is chrome.

Non relativistic gravity well ship:

Imagine a flying saucer. The gravity well generator can be rotated around this outside edge to create a 360° directional engine. Plus it's the perfect shape to shoot out of a railgun into space. Unfortunately the ship can only move on a two dimensional axis, so you'll need small thrusters to change the ships plane if you have to go somewhere that isn't aligned property.

Fortunately though, you can power these thrusters with hydrogen, because as you travel through spave, your gravity well will create locations with dense concentrations of matter than most of the empty void. Simply collect these as you go through to create fuel for jet thrusters. (Be advised, you aren't burning the hydrogen, just ejecting high pressure jets of it.)

Now the real problem is powering your ship in space, which I have to say depends on where you're going. If you stay close to our sun, or a different one, you could coat up in solar panels and rely mostly on that. If away from the sun you could do radioisotope thermalelectric generation, which is what powers satellites and probes. They don't produce tons of electricity, but you might have several or a really big one.

The thermoelectric generator could also work by aligning a spaceship so that one flat side faces the sun, and one side faces away. The temperature difference would be immense and you'd be able to have a rather large thermoelectric generator working.

You can also do something like a solar powered hydrolysis tank, and then a gas compressor, and finally a generator that uses hydrogen reacting with oxygen as fuel.  I like this kind because it works as a battery that goes father distances then regular solar power.

Comment: Hey Clay. You wouldn't need thrusters plus the gravity generator. The generator is your source of propulsion, but it pulls you instead of pushing you. Also, I like chrome too but I'd add wood accent panelling.

Comment: @Geuis The thrusters are only there to generate g force, since the gravity well won't accelerate you.

Comment: @Geuis Did not see the update, will change things accordingly.